# Can I use mysqlimport / LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using mysqlimport to get rows from a text file to a table easily like so:

```
mysqlimport -u root -p --local mytest employee.txt
```

Can I do this from a stored procedure?  All attempts so far have failed I'm afraid this may only be available using command line?  The objective is to have a job call a SP, this SP extracts rows from a text file (tab delimited), then the SP compares each row with an existing table, if found it will update, else insert.

Thanking you

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures execute on the server and do not have access to remote filesystems.

A rough equivalent of this is a call `LOAD DATA INFILE`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'employee.txt' INTO TABLE mytest
```

This requires `employee.txt` to reside on your server. The `--local` option requires the `mysqlimport` client to bridge that data in.

Comment: thank you for your time.  I dont fully understand what you have said about the --local option, what do you mean by this?  Also are you saying the 'LOAD DATA INFILE 'employee.txt' INTO TABLE mytest' can be run from a stored proc providing the txt file is on the server? Lastly, does mysqlimport also require the file to be on the server?  Thank you

Comment: The `--local` option allows you to import a local file to the server as the server cannot load files from your machine without assistance. A stored procedure would be limited to loading files on the server only.

Answer (score 0):

Load Data INFILE doesnt work with stored proc. you would like to use perl script or else to do this

Comment: How would you go about that?

Comment: REFER THIS:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737974/load-data-local-infile-gives-the-error-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this