# Import contents of mysql table from a txt file from ssh

Tags: ssh, mysql, mediatemple

I am trying to import contents of mysql table from a txt file.

I have already created dump of individual tables in .txt file. I then tried to import this txt file in my local server by **LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE**. It worked fine locally. But when I tried to import using the same method in live. I am getting *#1148 - The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version*. I searched and followed steps from these two threads:

- [PHPMyAdmin saying: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262403/phpmyadmin-saying-the-used-command-is-not-allowed-with-this-mysql-version)
- [access denied for load data infile in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221335/access-denied-for-load-data-infile-in-mysql#)

But it didn't work out. Now I am finding way to import these contents into the table from those txt files by ssh. Any help on how to do that from SSH will be great.

BTW, I am using mediatemple DV

TIA

Comment: You can't redirect it to the `mysql` executable?

Comment: I don't know about that. It's first time I am working on such big database with more than 5 million rows. Can you please clarify, what to I need to do?

Comment: `cat dump.sql | mysql -uroot -ppassword -hlocalhost`