# How to solve ERROR CODE:1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version , works fine in workbench

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I am trying to Excel VBA to upload text file into a table in Mysql. Local infile is enabled on the server

SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "local_infile"; this returns local_infile is ON. Also am able to run the LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE command on workbench. But when I try to run the upload macro , I am getting the below erro

ERROR CODE:1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version , works fine in workbench

The Excel ODBC connection is working fine. I am able  to download data into Excel from Mysql and also delete rows in Mysql from queries running on Excel. However, the load data command is giving error. How can I solve this issue.

Mysql server version - 5.6.10

Thanks,
Nanda

Comment: try via workbench to set     SET GLOBAL local_infile = 1;

Comment: Thanks, I am using AWS RDS Aurora Mysql. The local_infile is already set to 1 on the db parameter group. Also, some of my colleagues are able to run the uploader macro, it doesnt work for few of us

Comment: check on aws /etc/mysql/my.cnf to be sure and maybe check also what is happening in the sys log , maybe is mysqld is blocked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE not allowed over ODBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53733880/mysql-load-data-local-infile-not-allowed-over-odbc)